# formatting numbers in input with ngModel

Tags: angular

I've got an input linked to the object that contains relevant data:

```
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="element.number" name="someName">
```

element is an object with property number. number is of type number and it is always whole number.

I'd like to display a formated value of input (transform seconds into a more human readable format). Lets say `element.number` is `140`, than the displayed value is `00:02:20`. If the `element.number` is 22, than the displayed value is `00:00:22`. If `element.number` is `3670`, than the displayed value is  `01:01:10` and so on.

If the user than edits `00:00:22` to `00:01:44` than `element.number` gets updated to `104`.

For all the logic the app needs, `element.number` must be an integer. How should I go around this? Is there some pipe I can use on expressions? Should I split the input into 3 input fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';

        @Component({
          selector: 'app-root',
          template: '
         <div>
           <p>The number is {{number}}</p>
           <p>
             <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="formattednumbers.hrs" 
                name="hrs" (change)="updateNumber()">:
             <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="formattednumbers.mins" 
                name="mins" (change)="updateNumber()">:
             <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="formattednumbers.secs" 
                name="secs" (change)="updateNumber()">
           </p>
         </div>
         '
        })
        export class AppComponent {
          number = 140;
          formattednumbers: TimeFormatter;

          constructor() {
            this.formattednumbers = this.fancyTimeFormat(this.number);
          }

          fancyTimeFormat(time): TimeFormatter {
            // Hours, minutes and seconds
            const hrs = Math.floor(time / 3600);
            const mins = Math.floor((time % 3600) / 60);
            const secs = Math.floor(time % 60);

            const ret = {
              hrs: hrs,
              mins: mins,
              secs: secs
            };

            return ret;
          }

          updateNumber() {
            const h2s = this.formattednumbers.hrs * 3600;
            const m2s = this.formattednumbers.mins * 60;
            const s = this.formattednumbers.secs;
            this.number = h2s + m2s + s;
            this.formattednumbers = this.fancyTimeFormat(this.number);
          }
        }

        interface TimeFormatter {
          hrs: number;
          mins: number;
          secs: number;
        }
```

you can refactor the code a little bit more but the answer for your question is there i think :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look more in the html5 formats. Try this:

```
<input type="time" step="1" />
```

Works in:

https://html5test.com/compare/feature/form.time.step.html